# Donut Chart - arcTween transition with outer Radius

Tags: d3.js

Donut Chart - arcTween transition with outer Radius

Hi, my intention is in the donuts when the data are updated the donuts can grow with transitions.

I use this code for interpolate the arcs (works perfect) but i  add the interpolate for the donut and don't worked good, the donut are growing with transition  started in 0 and going to the new radius.

Arcs:

```
//SET ARC RADIUS
chart_vars_object.arc = d3.svg.arc()
    .outerRadius(chart_vars_object.general_radius)
    .innerRadius(0);
```

Paths:

```
//CREATE PATHS WITH ARC
    chart_vars_object.path = g.append("path")
        .attr("class","arc")
        .style({'cursor': 'pointer', 'opacity': '0.9'})
        .attr("fill", function(d) {
            return chart_vars_object.color(d.data.hash_taggeds_name);
        })
        .attr("d", chart_vars_object.arc)
        .each(function(d) {
            this._current = d;
        });
```

And when i update:

```
chart_vars_object.arc_update = d3.select(".pie_id_"+ id_update).selectAll(".arc_group").select(".arc")
                            .data(function(d) {
                                return chart_vars_object.pie(data_update.hash_taggeds_update);
                            })
                            .transition()
                            .duration(750)
                            .attrTween("d", arc_update_Tween);

function arc_update_Tween(d) {
                        this._current = this._current || d;
                        var interpolate_arcs  = d3.interpolate(this._current, d);
                        var interpolate_donut = d3.interpolate(chart_vars_object.arc.outerRadius()(), newradius);
                        this._current = interpolate_arcs(0);
                        return function(t) {
                            return chart_vars_object.arc.innerRadius(0).outerRadius(interpolate_donut(t))(interpolate_arcs(t));
                        };
                    }
```

any suggestion?

sorry for my english.-

Comment: So `chart_vars_object.arc.outerRadius()()` is 0?

Comment: No, with this my intention is  get the previous outerRadius and change with another. The initial value is 90

Comment: Well what you have been describing suggests that it is 0 or not defined or something like that. I'm also pretty sure that you don't need the additional `()` at the end.

Comment: If i use with one () in console i get "function (){return n}", but if i use  ()() i get the radius like 90.

Comment: Could you provide a complete working example please?

Comment: I found a solution, i create a ARC array for each donut and now it's working. Example : chart_vars_object.arcs_per_pie[id_update].outerRadius()()